# Understanding this solution to the longest substring without repetition problem in leetcode

Tags: python

So I'm trying to understand this solution for this problem. The goal here is to get the length of the longest substring from a string without having repeated characters.

How I understand it is that it goes character by character. Using the current index, it will subtract from the start position which is 0 because the the index initially starts 0. The addition of 1 is to compensate from starting at index 0.

If it encounters a duplicate character, it will shift the start position until no duplicates are found, this essentially separates the previous characters into a substring and starts at the position of the new substring with the duplicates, e.g. `abcab => "abc" and "ab"`. It will continue until the length longest substring with no duplicates is found.

The code for the solution is as seen below:

```
class Solution(object):
        def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
            """
            :type s: str
            :rtype: int
            """
            used = {}
            max_length = start = 0
            
            for i,c in enumerate(s):
                if c in used and start<=used[c]:
                    start = used[c]+1
                else:
                    max_length = max(max_length,i-start+1)
                used[c] = i
            return max_length
```

What I don't understand is the `start<=used[c]` and `used[c] = i` part of this solution, what does it do? Can someone clarify with me?

EDIT: I understand that the dictionary is being used to keep track of the character count. I just don't understand the logic of it. Sorry, I should've clarified.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: `used` is being used like a bookmark for last seen position of already seen characters. Explain the question first before providing solution. Someone who is not familiar with the question or platform won't be able to answer this or will have hard time understanding.

Comment: @รยקคгรђשค I've edited my question reflect your suggestion. But anyway, after taking a look again, so `used[c]` is used only when a duplicate is found, it will compare from the starting position of 0 and move the start position by 1 to reflect a new substring. Is correct to assume so? I still don't quite understand the `start<=used[c]` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to form a longest sub-string without repeating characters.

**Algorithm Psuedocode:**

1. Start with an empty string, with `start` as begin index of string. You want to extend the string until you get a duplicate character.
2. There are 2 possibilities for each character, either a character has been seen for the first time or character is already seen before. After each character we update bookmark `used` to keep track of last seen index.
3. a) If the character is not seen before, you can safely extend the current string.

   Or

   b) If the character was seen before, then we can only extend the string if it is not part of current string (`start > used[c]`). If it is part of the string ( `start <= used[c]`), you will need to update the sub-string's begin index `start` with index next to the last seen of current character as we don't want the characters to repeat, i.e. `start = used[c] + 1`. Since you are shortening the string in the latter case, maximal string won't be ending at this position.

Comment: so for example, the string `"tmmzxt"`, for `used['t']` will contain the number 0, `start` would be `2` because `m` is duplicated in position `2`. 

Given `m` is in `used` and `start<=used[c]` which can be seen also as `0<=1`, `start` would become 2 since `start = 1+1`.

Back to the example, if the loop reaches the final `t`, `start<=used[c]` will not execute because `2<=0` and then it will go to `max_length = max(3,5-2+1)` returning the value of 4 as the longest substring is 4 in length. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you have understood. @cswannabe. If a character `c` exists in `used` then `used[c]` will be the last seen index of that character.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thank you for taking your time to confirm with me.